# Search collection and retrieve model backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, collections, models

I am trying to search a collection for a model attribute and then grab and return the entire model ?

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
      a: '',
      b: '',
      c: '',
      d: '',
      e: ''
  }
});
```

My collection has around 100 of myModels.

I am trying to search through the collection by `a`, find it and then return the entire `myModel` of `a` so I can access the other attributes ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the `where` method on Backbone collections, here in the docs:

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

So, given an instance of MyCollection called myCollection that has MyModels in it, you can say:

```
var foundModels = myCollection.where({a:'some value'});
```

and `foundModels` will contain an array of the models you seek

BTW, if you are doing a more complex search, use the `filter` method instead, passing a function as the first argument that returns true on the desired match:

```
var modelsWhoseAStartsWithA = myCollection.filter(function(anyModel) {
    var startsWithA = new RegExp(/^[aA]/);
    return startsWithA.test(anyModel.get('a'));
});
```

Comment: thanks @georgedyer - it will return a unique model in my case so that I can then use `foundModel.get('e')` for example. will this allow me to d that ?

Comment: yes, these methods return arrays of models that are in your collection

Comment: yep - just have to select the array ;) i.e. `foundModels[0]`. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: no prob: here's a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/georgedyer/YVQC3/3/