# Backbone Collection: custom comparator

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**I want:** to search through Backbone.Collectio by complex criteria. To be more precise, I have `startTime` & `endTime` properties of `TimePeriod` obj, and I want to select `TimePeriod` to which belongs specific moment.

**Example:** I have moment equals 12045, and I need to go through collection of timeperiods and check for each:

```
belongsToTimeperiod: function(timePeriod, moment) {
    return (timePeriod.startTime < moment && timePeriod.endTime > moment);
}
```

**Question:** *is that possible to make Backbone.Collection use my comparator? How?*

**Code: [optional]**

```
var TimePeriod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'startTime': '',
        'endTime': ''
    },
    validate: function(attrs) {
        if (!startTime) return 'You missed startTime';
        if (!endTime) return 'You missed endTime';
    }
}
```

And collection of that objects:

```
var TimePeriods = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TimePeriod
});
```

Comment: This what you looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450011/search-collection-and-retrieve-model-backbonejs

Comment: @levi No, because they use method filter. The problem is `TimePeriods` are a big collection of sequential time periods. So what I need is a binary search instead of iteration through all elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchTerm=...;
function searchModel(int start, int end){
    var i=(start+end)/2;
       var model=collection.at(i);             //http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-at
       if(model.get('property')>searchTerm){   //Collection is sorted on this 'property'
            return searchModel(start,i);
       }else if(model.getProperty()<searchTerm){
           return searchModel(i,end);
       }
   return model;
}
```

Untested code, haven't written binary search algo. in a long time. Hope so it gives you an idea.